# What are the rules that govern Deadpool's regenerative powers?

Tags: marvel, deadpool

Most of my doubts about his healing ability were answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115815/what-is-the-limit-of-deadpools-regenerative-ability).

Deadpool has one of the greatest healing factors in the Marvel universe. As mentioned [here](http://marvel.com/universe/Deadpool_(Wade_Wilson)):

> Deadpool possesses a ***superhuman healing factor*** derived from that of the mutant Wolverine that allows him to regenerate damaged or destroyed areas of his cellular structure at a rate far greater than that of an ordinary human. As such, ***he can regrow severed limbs or vital organs***.

However, I have a slight confusion about Deadpool's regenerative limit. What is the deciding factor which chooses to grow into a complete 'Pool? Hypothetically, for example, if he's blasted into several pieces, will we have multiple 'Pools? (that would be fun though!)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Your suggestion link shows how the pieces "merge" to form a Deadpool again. That didn't answer my question.

Comment: The duplicate is asking the same question just because it doesn't have a satisfactory answer yet doesn't mean it isn't a dupe. If you would like a better answer you should bounty the dupe and explain why in the reason,

Comment: @Shreedhar There are several other answers there too, enough to at least allow you to form a personal educated guess. Keep in mind that, if they don't provide you with a more delineated canon answer, it may be because there simply isn't one.